# Why are the green traces thick at the peaks of the cycle? What causes this ‘roughness’ in the oscilloscope reading?

Tags: oscilloscope

[image: Oscilloscope data]

### [image: Roughness]

This is probably a very basic question but I could not find the answer to it online. I just want to make sure - is the roughness caused by electromagnetic interference?

Comment: Yes (12 more to go) well.. that's a general term, any noise, power supply noise is usually the worst culprit. However, it can also be high frequency ringing on the signal. You need to zoom in and see if it is consistant with the edge, but it looks like noise to me.

Comment: Either that's the noise laid on top of earlier periods (overlaid/overlayed?). Or that's just how every period actually looks. My **guess** is that it's overlayed noise. But you're the one who got the zoom knob and can actually verify this.

Comment: Two possibilities here its either noise on the signal or that is just the height of the line width. If it goes away when you set the coupling to GND/0V then its noise.  You don't see it during the vertcal edges because this is up and down, not side to side so not visible.

Comment: @HarrySvensson good point, a lot of it is a scope artifact. I'm so used to digital I forgot about that :)

Comment: \*Forehead Slap\* Everything, everything is noisy

Comment: to make sure that it is not interference, do a "single-shot" sweep

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Roughness means some variations of signal:
 1. High frequency additive oscillations (or noise). Try using much lower time/div to see them. Try to limit input bandwidth to suppress them.
 2. Low frequency addidive oscillations or amplitude modulation. Try using much higher time/div. Also, try single-shot trigger mode to suppress multiple waveform accumulation on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Some of what you're seeing is undoubtedly due to simple ringing.

The simple fact is that a perfect square wave requires infinite frequency, which (obviously) isn't possible.

With a limited bandwidth, the signal will show some ringing, so (even at best) it looks something like this:

[image]

The red line shows the theoretical wave. The green shows up to the fifth harmonic of the fundamental, and the blue line up to the fifteenth harmonic.

Note how even in a simulated picture like this with no noise added at all, we still get what looks like a much thicker line at the peaks.

I must admit that I'm somewhat (extremely?) puzzled by some of the comments. Let's consider this:

[image]

Now, I'm the first to admit that this scope *is* fairly old (probably older than some of the people who wrote comments). I don't think it's being restricted to a mere 600 MHz bandwidth is quite enough to qualify as a "horrible oscilloscope" (you'd certainly think 600 MHz would be enough to show a 1 KHz signal *fairly* accurately). It's showing the 1 KHz square wave generated by the scope itself, so I don't think that's somehow started to produce output at 100 MHz or something a whole lot faster than 1 KHz. I'm using a direct coax connection from the generator to the input.

Does somebody here honestly believe that a 1 meter coax cable is going to let huge amounts of noise in to cause the peaks to be bright, even though the rise and fall are so dim they're nearly invisible? If so, how do they believe that anybody would ever stand any chance at all of measuring anything when using a normal scope probe, which inevitably has at least a *little* unshielded wiring involved?

For those who are convinced that you just can't see the overshoot and ringing without infinite bandwidth, let's take a look at a somewhat zoomed in view:

[image]

Now remember: this is a direct coax connection, so what we're seeing is only what's left when the signal has been terminated quite carefully (50 Ohm cable going to a 50 Ohm input). Even so, there's a little overshoot and ringing--under almost any normal circumstances, we'd expect to see (quite a bit) more.

Now, it is almost certainly true that with a phosphor display like this oscilloscope uses, part of the difference in brightness is due to the speed at which the electron beam is moving at a given time. We set a specific speed at which the beam traverses the display (e.g., 1 millisecond). When it's traveling (approximately) horizontally, it spends a relatively large amount of time lighting up the phosphor in a fairly small area. When it gets to the rising or falling part of the wave, it's still moving at the same speed horizontally, *but* it's also moving at relatively high speed vertically--thus, it's only spending a very small amount of time exciting the phosphor along those sections.

With a raster display, it's pretty much up to the people writing the software to decide whether to simulate this effect or not. I haven't looked at the software of the particular oscilloscope used by the OP, but it wouldn't strike me as terribly surprising if they decided to imitate what a conventional trace of the same signal would look like.

That does *not*, however, render what I said previously incorrect--that *some* of what you're seeing is from ringing in the circuit. No matter how careful you are to eliminate it, there's undoubtedly going to be at least *some* noise as well--but in the setup I've shown above, we see roughly the same effect in a signal that should be *extremely* low in noise--far below anything that could possibly account for the effect shown.

Comment: It's a 1 kHz square wave, for those artifacts to appear, it has to be a horrible oscilloscope, or a *high* (more than 1 kHz) frequency square wave.

Comment: That Gibbs phenomenon you are talking about is non-causal, i.e. needs a perfectly squared bandwidth and is hence theoretical only. Such a circuit cannot be realized and so Gibbs ringing cannot ever seen in real life.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: the frequency barely matters at all. To the degree that the input wave matters, it's the rise/fall time that really matters. A 1 kHz wave with a fast rise time will show roughly the same ringing as a 1 GHz wave with the same rise time. A lot here also depends on the termination into which you're feeding the wave.

Comment: @carloc: Seems to me that rather the opposite is true: with infinite bandwidth (feeding a perfect termination, etc.) you get a perfect square wave. With any real system, you *don't* get the infinite bandwidth, and so you see overshoot, ringing, etc. I've certainly seen overshoot and ringing on a real oscilloscope in real life (though it wasn't as clean and symmetrical as it's shown here, of course).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: limited bandwidth (or limited number of harmonics) does not at all explain why the graph is thick. The reason is simply noise (HF) or a low frequency added signal (e.g. added line voltage interference). See Eugene K's answer.

Comment: As you have demonstrated, overshoot and ringing decays. That's why it cannot explain the phenomena seen in OP's pictures.

Comment: @pipe: it decays to some degree, sure. With extremely careful termination like I've used, it even decays pretty quickly--but we don't know that the OP's picture has nearly that good of termination (and Eugene K's answer certainly doesn't seem to fit at all--a 1 meter coax picking up this amount of noise sounds pretty unbelievable.).

Comment: @curd: Please see the traces I've added above. It' hard to be certain exactly how much of the effect seen by the OP can be attributed to harmonics--but I've shown enough to say that the effect persists, even when noise has been reduced *far* below the level at which it could account for much of anything. (i.e., harmonics may not be the whole story, but interference barely even qualifies for a footnote to the story).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: the harmonics (or overshoot) not only decay very quickly (as your colored graph with the harmonics also shows) but harmonics are also **in phase** with the fundamental wave and therefore don't form a smeadred thick line like uncorrelated noise or interference does

Comment: @curd: They decay quickly when you're driving an impedance-matched, low-reactance circuit. Reactance can prolong ringing almost indefinitely. When you digitally sample the signal and portray a line as a minimum of one pixel wide, what started as a high-frequency signal can end up looking like a thick, smeared line.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: please read my whole argument: as I said harmonics and overshoot is **in phase** with the fundamental wave (=main signal the scope's trigger is in sync with), therefor it never makes the trace thick for a long time (as your example trace shows very good). The thick line is, however, a typical sign of a **uncorrelated** (i.e. out of phase) signal added which can be either noise or uncorrelated interference. Your own example show clearly that overshoot does **not** make the trace thick.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: if overshoot or harmonics don't decay quickly they also don't make the trace thick; they'd just make it different (curvy)

Comment: I've read what you've said, but a fair amount of it is obvious nonsense. Just for example, the ringing is at higher frequency than the base wave. It goes from in phase to 180 degrees out of phase, and back to in phase *several* times during one peak of the base signal. Putting "in phase" in bold-face isn't going to change that.